# Adding another input field when clicking on a button

Tags: html, forms, button, input

I did some research and I wasn't able to find anything on it. I have an input where the person can input a location, but I also want them to be able to add another, alternate location. I basically need a button to open a form. Here is the code for the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Location: </label>
    <input name = "cityForm" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zipcode or City" 
        width: 50%;>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the button:

```
<center>
    <button id="locationAlternate" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Alternate Location
    </button>
</center>
```

Comment: The title says you want to add another input, your question says you want to open a form. You need to clarify what you need and add more detail. Can you not just add another input for the alternate location? Also add what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

```js
   $('#locationAlternate').on('click',function() {

 $('#location').append('<div class="form-group" id="altloc"><label for="">Alternate Location: </label> <input name = "AltcityForm" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Alternate Location" width: 50%;></div>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" id="location">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Location: </label>
        <input name = "cityForm" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Zipcode or City" width: 50%;>
</div> 

<button id="locationAlternate" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Alternate Location</button>
```

Comment: I just get all of the characters below the button itself. Am i supposed to get rid of the dollar signs?

Comment: Is there any way I could make it repeat. So that the button stays and the forms can keep going down?

Comment: repeat? can you elaborate

Comment: When I click the button it adds the form, which is perfect. But it also gets rid of the button. I was wondering if it's possible that the button stays and moves below that form when a new form is being created. So whenever you click the button it adds more input fields

Comment: check my answer above and click "run code snippet". the form moves below and the button stays

Comment: Yes. But you also can't click on it more than once. You can't create multiple fields. Only 2